# Insert external content in a wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to insert content from other blogs into my blog page.

Lets say there is a blog with content and images...

I want to display all of that content on my blog page in wordpress.

But the technique should be dynamic...e.g if the content updates then the content 
on my blog page should also update.

What is the proper method to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

does this page have an rss feed? if so, then you can use an rss feed plugin for wordpress to create posts for you.  if not, then you will have to create your own script to download the data and post to your blog.